# Sharepoint 2013 Search stop working

Tags: 2013, search

At Search it show me a 100 000 results, but when I try to search in site it's not showing any results. I change only alternative address. How Could I find out why it not showing any results?

Comment: You need to add more information to this post, it is very hard to understand what happens, and where.

Comment: 10000 is it showing in the crawl log?

Comment: More it showing 100 000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too.

You changed/added a new Address/URL? The Address of your Content Source has to be in "Default" Zone in your Alternate Access Mapping, because the *Default URL* in AAM is used in the Search Configuration.

Otherwise, "Search This Site" shows no results.

Check this out for more Details: http://blog.dafran.ca/post/2011/07/02/SharePoint-does-not-return-any-search-results.aspx

Edit: To add an additional URL to default zone: Central Administration > System Settings > Alternate Access Mapping > Select "Alternate Access Mapping Collection" (top right) then > "Add Internal URLs"

Comment: Jes I done this. How Could I bring back this search alive.

Comment: I write a link adress and after thiss all changed to the link adres not the server name.

Comment: How to add another default adress ? Please help.

Comment: Didn't work? In my case I'm using only one Default Address (https) and the others, like  Intranet, Custom etc. are for HTTP, non-secure. But in IIS I only configured HTTPS Access. 

So first, what do you mean with "link address" ? You only have to put the URL of your WebApplication in Default Zone. And this URL has to be in your Search Content Source too.

Or maybe you could provide some examples?

Comment: I have got two Default Adress, One domain name, and one server name

Comment: Which one do you want to use? I wouldn't recommend using both as default...

Comment: Domain name is http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com and serwer name http://serwer08. I Echange http://serwer08. for domain Adres :http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com and it stopped work:

Comment: I wan't to use domain name, but at it no one search is finding :  'http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com'

Comment: The clawling show me only links for serwer08

Comment: Ok... so "Search This Site" doesn't work in all Web Applications in all Site Collections, or only in one specific? I would do following: 1. Put Domain Name in Default Zone of your WebApplication (only 1 URL per WebApp). 2. Check if access via domain name is working. 3. Check all Content Sources. Domain Name has to be in a content source. If that doesn't help, then - only for testing - do a rollback and use server name again. Does the Search now showing results? My guess is that something's missing in your Content Sources configuration...

Comment: First it worked with one and two, next I changed serwer name to domain name, and then the site is working, but search not. Now when I run Clawling it show me that it find out a 100 000 result on serwer name, and none on domain name.

Comment: How to add 2 Default in Alternate Access Mapping.

Comment: CA > System Settings > Alternate Access Mapping > Select "Alternate Access Mapping Collection" (top right) then > "Add Internal URLs"

Comment: Yes but when I'm adding the secound it show me this error: http://serwer08 is already routed to the Extranet zone of another application. Remove that mapping or use a different URL.

Comment: The error tells you that in another AAM you already set the exact same URL. Check your Access Mappings...

Comment: I chacking all the times, but now it's works :) I set only serwer name on custom and it works :)